# Creating a TypeScript definition for ASP.Net AJAX String.format method?

Tags: typescript

String.format is this one: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397701(v=vs.100).aspx

Note, this is a static method on the String class, not a method on the prototype.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't declare static methods on an interface, so you may need to actually override the `lib.d.ts` definition of String:

```
declare var String: {
    new (value?: any): String;
    (value?: any): string;
    prototype: String;
    fromCharCode(...codes: number[]): string;
    format(format: string, ...args: any[]) : string;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this question was closed as not a real question.  You pretty much confirmed what I was thinking.  I really don't want to change lib.d.ts though, since ASPNET AJAX isn't used in all my projects.

Comment: Instead, I decided to just cheat a bit to get around the TS compiler warning.

var StringStatic : any = String;
StringStatic.format(xxx,yyy)   // no more warnings.  But no strongly-typed intellisense either.